# How do I force Windows to play sound through the speakers only when a USB headset isn't connected?

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers, usb-headset

I'm using a speaker set connected through the green audio jack and a headset which I connect through USB. My problem is that every time I connect/disconnect my headset, I have to go through a lot of settings/restart some programs to make the sound go through the speakers again.

What I want is to have audio play through the headset **when it's connected**, but if I disconnect the headset, I want the audio to automatically play through the speakers.

For example, if I connect/disconnect the headset while listening to music, I have to restart the application to make the music play through the correct speaker/headset, and it shouldn't be that inconvenient.

(I found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/31097/how-to-redirect-sound-to-usb-headset-when-plugged-in) somewhat relevant topic, but the problem is that it doesn't really give an answer. (Also, it is 2 years old.))

Comment: My windows 7 laptop plays sound through the internal speakers, but when I plug a pair of headphones in it only plays through the headphones. I have realtek high definition audio drivers, but I don't know how it is set up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any automatic solution, but here are several hotkey-using solutions you could look at :

[How to change the default audio device with a hotkey](http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2010/06/16/windows-7-tip-how-to-change-the-default-audio-device-with-a-hot/)
A AutoHotKey script to switch between audio sources

[Soundswitch](http://blog.contriving.net/2009/05/04/a-hotkey-to-switch-between-headphones-and-speakers-soundswitch/)
Switch between headphones and speakers (have a look at [version 3](http://blog.contriving.net/2010/10/02/easier-switching-of-sound-devices-in-windows-with-soundswitch-3-0dev1/))

The thread [Audio playback through headphones and speakers](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/audio-playback-through-headphones-and-speakers/faf2cb4a-b853-44a6-a7ee-37abaeb327c5) has some ideas that may be
worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

[AHK usb device detection](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/49386-launching-a-script-when-a-specific-usb-device-is-connected/)

this one will allow you to detect a specific usb device and run ... when that happens.

there is a util for usb flash drives to auto run a script not sure if it will do the same for the audio device.  you could combine the sound switch harrymc suggested with the detction routine to hopefully switch automagically.

[usb media util](http://mattcollinge.wordpress.com/software/usb-detect-and-launch/)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible due to architectural design. The application playing the sound receives a direct handle to the output device (which enables, among others, sound over RDP) and when the device is disconnected, the program doesn’t have anything to play sound to. It could be theoretically possible to virtualise the audio stack to enable switching output devices, but it would be infeasible due to latency issues.